# Using LINQ to create a simple login

Tags: asp.net, database, linq, authentication

I'm an C# ASP.NET beginner, so please excuse anything that's... not quite right!

In short, I want to create a really basic login system: one which runs through a database and uses sessions so that only logged in users can access certain pages. I know how to do most of that, but I'm stuck with querying data with LINQ on the login page.

On the login page, I have a DropDownList to select a username, a Textbox to type in a password and a button to login (I also have a literal for errors). The DropDownList is databound to a datatable called DT_Test. DT_Test contains three columns: UsernameID (int), Username (nchar(30)) and Password (nchar(30)). UsernameID is the primary key.

I want to make the button's click event query data from the database with the DropDownList and Textbox, in order to check if the username and password match. But I don't know how to do this...

Current Code (not a lot!):

Front End:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login_Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login_Login_Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Login Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="LoginTest" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Username" runat="server" Height="20px" 
            DataTextField="txt">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TB_Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="B_Login" runat="server" onclick="B_Login_Click" Text="Login" />
        <br />
        <asp:Literal ID="LI_Result" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Back End:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Login_Login_Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Binder();
            }
    }

    private void Binder()
    {
        using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            DDL_Username.DataSource = from x in db.DT_Honeys select new { x.UsernameID, txt = x.Username };
            DDL_Username.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void B_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TB_Password.Text != "")
        {
            using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have spent hours searching and trying different code, but none of it seems to fit in for this context.

Anyway, help and tips appreciated, thank you very much!

- I am aware of security risks etc. but this is not a live website or anything, it is simply for testing purposes as a beginner. *

Updated code:

Back End:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Login_Page_Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Tester();
        }
    }

    private void Tester()
    {
        using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            DDL_Username.DataSource = from x in db.DT_Honeys select new { id = x.UsernameID, txt = x.Username };
            DDL_Username.DataValueField = "id";
            DDL_Username.DataTextField = "txt";
            DDL_Username.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void B_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TB_Password.Text != "")
        {
            using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {
                DT_Honey blah = new DT_Honey();
                blah = db.DT_Honeys.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UsernameID == int.Parse(DDL_Username.SelectedValue.ToString()));

                if (blah != null)
                {
                    if (TB_Password.Text.ToString().Trim() == blah.Password.ToString())
                    {
                        LI_Result.Text = "Credentials correct.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LI_Result.Text = "Error: credentials are incorrect.";
                }
                }
                else
                {
                    LI_Result.Text = "Error: null value.";
                }

            }
    }

    }
}
```

Front End:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login_Page_Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login_Page_Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Logi Page Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="LoginPageTest" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Username" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TB_Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="B_Login" runat="server" onclick="B_Login_Click" Text="Login" />
    <br />
    <asp:Literal ID="LI_Result" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

- I have checked the database aspects, and it is all fine in terms of primary key, columns, actual data, and dataclasses.

---

Same with textbox:

Back End:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Login_Login_Page_2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void B_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TB_Username.Text.ToString().Trim() != "" && TB_Password.Text.ToString().Trim() != "")
        {
            using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {
                DT_Honey Login = new DT_Honey();
                Login = db.DT_Honeys.SingleOrDefault(y => y.UsernameID == int.Parse(TB_Username.Text.ToString().Trim()));

                if (Login != null)
                {
                    if (TB_Password.Text.Trim() == Login.Password.ToString().Trim())
                    {
                        LI_Result.Text = "Yeah! The credentials you entered were correct!";
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    LI_Result.Text = "Oops! There was an error with the credentials you entered; please try again.";
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            LI_Result.Text = "Wow! Please fill out <b>both</b> the Username and Password text fields to login; thank you.";
        }
    }
}
```

Front End:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login_Page_2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login_Login_Page_2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Login Page 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="LoginPage2" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TB_Username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TB_Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="B_Login" runat="server" onclick="B_Login_Click" Text="Login" />
        <br />
        <asp:Literal ID="LI_Result" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As frenchie said, do not try to roll your own authentication system! But why would you want to provide a dropdown with user names and IDs? Doing so exposes all your user names, and also expose userID-s. Why would you want to do that? Also, if you have a significant number of users, you would send a lot of data to your client this way.

Comment: Look at edit / other comments. By the way, username IDs are not displayed; only the username is displayed.

Comment: The answers aren't much use to anyone visiting now you have deleted the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you?:

```
protected void B_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TB_Password.Text != "")
        {
            using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {
                var user = db.DT_Test.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == DDL_Username.SelectedText);

                if (user == null) 
                {
                    // whoops something's wrong (no matching username in db)
                }

                if (user.Password == TB_Password.Text)
                {
                    // do something (correct password)
                }
                else
                {
                    // something else (incorrect password)
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

However, best practice would be to use a standard membership provider for ASP.NET.  Then you don't have to be in the business of setting up your own membership schema in a database.  (It looks as though you're storing passwords in clear text, but a membership provider will fix that and handle the details for you.)

[MSDN Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)

**Edit**  You'll probably want to change the Binder code so that your drop down items' IDs match up with the database ID numbers:

```
private void Binder()
{
    using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        DDL_Username.DataSource = from x in db.DT_Honeys select new { id = x.UsernameID, txt = x.Username };
        DDL_Username.DataValueField = "id";
        DDL_Username.DataTextField = "txt";
        DDL_Username.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It is almost working. The problem is when I type a correct password for the username, the literal returns the password is incorrect error (where you put //something else (incorrect password). I think the problem is with the var statement. I change SelectedText to SelectedValue.ToString() (and without to string) but it returns the mentioned error. I think it needs to be var user = db.DT_Test.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == int.Parse(DDL_Username.SelectedValue.ToString())); because UsernameID is primary key. But this throws an error 'Input string was not in a correct format'.

Comment: If I'm correct, this code assumes you are storing plain text passwords in your db, but you really should not do that!

Comment: Sure, with your changes it should work with `var user = db.DT_Test.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UsernameID == int.Parse(DDL_Username.SelectedValue.ToString()));`  (I just changed `x.Username` to `x.UsernameID`.

Comment: @AkosLukacs Yes, this has been mentioned in this and another answer.

Comment: Hahaha I typed it wrong in the comment but I did actually used UsernameID. But it still throws 'Input string was not in a correct format'. Hmm...

Comment: I saw that, but please, do not show code to ppl that works with plain text passwords...

Comment: I'm a beginner, what do you expect? MD5 encryption and whatever else before being able to query data? Hahaha, I've got to start somewhere! And this login system will never be on a live website. Maybe if you helped like hmqcnoesy, I could get on to security issues now.

Comment: Use forms authentication, that deals with hashing and salting passwords, so you don't have to worry about it...

Comment: @JDWebs - See the edited answer.  I added code for your Binder() method - where the dropdown list is bound to a collection of an anonymous type.  I added the "id" property name, then set the text and value properties for the drop down list.  Using that Binder() code, I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work for you:  `var user = db.DT_Test.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UsernameID == int.Parse(DDL_Username.SelectedValue.ToString()));`

Comment: Sorry, I have just discovered this is not a server issue; it is a problem with the code. Why is such a simple thing going wrong?!

Comment: So the problem is still "The input string was not in the correct format?"  And it is happening when you try to int.Parse the selected value of the dropdownlist?

Comment: I have just created a whole new web site to test this on. The error is no longer thrown, so I'm guessing there was some conflicts or small error in the last one. However, now when the correct password is entered, the literal says it is wrong! @hmqcnoesy Once again, thank you for your continued help.

Comment: What is your code that sets the text of the literal?  If you want to post more of your code, I'm sure we can find the problem.

Comment: @hmqcnoesy I have edited the actual question with my new code. I have checked the database aspects, and it is all fine in terms of primary key, columns, actual data, and dataclasses. Thanks!

Comment: When an exception is thrown in the debugger, if you hover over `TB_Password.Text`, what does it show you is the value of the Text property?  And if you hover over `blah.Password` what does it show you for its value?

Comment: No exception is thrown; all that happens is the `if (TB_Password.Text.ToString().Trim() == blah.Password.ToString())` returns no, when it should say yes. Because no is returned, the literal 's text is "Error: credentials are incorrect". Is there any other way of seeing the values of the TB_Password.text and blah.Password ?

Comment: Yes, put a breakpoint on the line `if (TB_Password.Text.ToString().Trim() == blah.Password.ToString())`.  Then F5 to start the app with debugging.  In your app, input the correct password, and click the button.  The program execution will stop at the breakpoint, and you can hover over the code to inspect the values in memory.

Comment: Aha! The database password has a ton of spaces after it - could this be the problem? But when I try to get rid of them and hit enter in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, it still puts spaces after it?

Comment: Sounds like the data type in SQL server pads to 30 chars with spaces.  I'd just put a trim on the password in your comparison.

Comment: @hmqcnoesy Oh dear! I have repeated the code in the actual project with a **textbox** but it still returns 'input string was not in the correct format' :/. It's literally the same but with a textbox .Text.ToString().Trim() as opposed to DDL.SelectedValue etc. I have tried it with correct and incorrect credentials, but with both the error is thrown. And when debugging, the values are correct 'JDWebs' as username and 'Abc123' as password. If you are of course still available to help, do yo want me to paste the whole code?

Comment: @hmqcnoesy Thanks! I have put it in the question.  I am using the exact same datatable with the same columns and data; the only change is the code I've shown.

Comment: It looks like you've still got that `int.Parse` in there.  Since you're trying to parse 'JDWebs' into an integer, it's throwing an exception.

Comment: But it works with the DDL? I'm guessing it's because the DDL has a datasource or something?

Comment: It works in the dropdownlist because the selected value is the UsernameID (an integer) but the value you type in the textbox is a Username (a string).  In HTML, an `option` can have a displayed text and an underlying value.  In your case, the UsernameID is the underlying value.  You can see this by viewing the source in the browser.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for letting me know. I will try and figure out how to get a text box to do it then! I only used a DDL to test a datasource!

Answer (score 3):

Since you're a self-described beginner, I'd really **recommend using the native asp.net login controls.** It's very likely that your code is less secure than the login control that 100's of engineers have spent years working on. Is there really a compelling reason for you to build your own custom login?? To begin with, doing what you're doing relies on storing unencrypted passwords....

**You're introducing potentially serious security vulnerabilities in your application by redoing the login control yourself!!**

Comment: Please read my edit; thanks for the heads up though :).

Comment: @JDWebs: ok, no problem. Sometimes you need to find out what doesn't work to get to the working solution. The login control is actually pretty easy to setup; you should try it out.